# Woocommerce Ajax add to cart redirect to homepage

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, themes

I am using Woocommerce 3.9.2, Wordpress 5.3.2 and Phlox shop theme (Version 2.4.22) and I have problem with AJAX add to cart. 
When I go into shop page and click add to cart random project it redirects to homepage. But when I go to single product page and then press add to cart it works as it should. 
Where could be the problem ?
Site link here [enter link description here](https://eogame.eu/rietumi2/?post_type=product)

Comment: My guess is your theme is responsible, which is 3rd party and off-topic here, I'd try reaching out to them.

Comment: How can responsible theme can be off-topic. I am simply asking for advice and a lead where could I locate a problem. As here are lot of highly experienced wordpress dev's that I am.

Comment: This stack just doesn't support 3rd party stuff, the theme author would be much more equipped to help.